# Trying to override magento-customer layout XML

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3

I want to override the layout of magento-customer in my theme.

The vendor path is

```
/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml
```

And its code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Dashboard</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customer_account_dashboard_top" as="top"/>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="account/dashboard/info.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Address" name="customer_account_dashboard_address" as="address" template="account/dashboard/address.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now I am trying to override in my theme,

```
app/design/frontend/Oneclout/jblashes/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_index.xml
```

and the code is

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    -->
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
                <action method="setPageTitle">
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Dashboard</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceContainer name="content">

                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="account/dashboard/info.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Address" name="customer_account_dashboard_address" as="address" template="account/dashboard/address.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
            </referenceContainer>
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customer_account_dashboard_top" as="top"/>
        </body>
    </page>
```

I just want to override this.

Comment: There are no difference between original and your custom layout

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya    I moved this block on last   <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customer_account_dashboard_top" as="top"/>
        </body>

Comment: when I change in vendor  its working perfect.

Comment: use <referenceContainer name="content">

                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="account/dashboard/info.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Address" name="customer_account_dashboard_address" as="address" template="account/dashboard/address.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customer_account_dashboard_top" as="top"/>
            </referenceContainer>

Comment: in body tag ? @RakeshJesadiya

Comment: yes just move the position on your content element

Comment: No , that container is dont know where gone not appearing on page. @RakeshJesadiya

Comment: maybe I need to add some block on override layout to tell vendor that its override file ?  I read somewhere but didnt get that. maybe its problem ? @RakeshJesadiya

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>

        <move element="customer_account_dashboard_top" destination="content" after="customer_account_dashboard_address" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: still no luck. I pasted this in override folder

Comment: Have you clear cache?

Comment: yes. I cleared then upgrade and then di:compile

Comment: jsut updated code please check

Comment: Now not disappearing but occurring on top.

Comment: please check above code is workign fine

Comment: perfect thank you brother . thank you so much. Is this layout overriding or extending ?

Comment: glad to know its help you. Its call overriding.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
<move element="customer_account_dashboard_top" destination="content" after="customer_account_dashboard_address">
```

inside the `<body>` tag of:

> app/design/frontend/Oneclout/jblashes/Oneclout_jblashes/layout/default.xml

it should work also in:

> app/design/frontend/Oneclout/jblashes/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_index.xml

Comment: it will decrease priority of vendor customer_account_index.xml ?

Comment: @Learner It won't overwrite the vendor customer_account_index.xml, it will just move the element where you want it to go. And it is good practice to have all your custom **<move>** elements in your themes **default.xml** (`app/design/frontend/Oneclout/jblashes/Oneclout_jblashes/layout/default.xml`) so you have them all in one place for future situations.

Comment: but its not working :(

Comment: It's working for me...did you clear static files and cache?